# Question about inverse of a conformal map is also holomorphic (Stein and Shakarchi)

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

Stein and Shakarchi, has the following proof for the proposition that the inverse of a conformal map is holomorphic, as follows:
[image: page1]
[image: page2]

I don't understand how $f(z)-f(z_{0}) = a(z-z_{0})^k + G(z)$ for all z near $z_{0}$ with $a \neq 0, k \geq 2$ and G vanishing to order $K+1$ at $z_{0}$?

I know that since f is holomorphic I can express it as the power series representation as $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}(z-z_{0})^n \forall z \in D$, for the disk D centered at $z_{0}$, and that the coefficients $a_{n} = \frac{f^{(n)}(z_{0})}{n!}$ for all $n \geq 0$. So using that definition, $f^{1}(z_{0})=0$ so $a_{1} = 0$. Therefore $f(z)=a_{0}$. And $f(z_{0})=0$. So $f(z)-f(z_{0}) = a_{0}$. Obviously that is not what he is saying.

Answer (score 1):

If you write $$f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n (z-z_0)^n,$$ you know that and $f'(z_0)=0,$ then you can re-write this as $$f(z)-f(z_0)=\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n.$$ Say that $a_k$ is the first non-zero coefficient on the right, where $k\geq 2$. Then, this can be expressed as $$\sum\limits_{n=k}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n=a_k(z-z_0)^k+G(z),$$ where $$G(z)=\sum\limits_{n=k+1}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n=(z-z_0)^{k+1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+k+1}(z-z_0)^n.$$ $G$ vanishes to order $k+1$ at $z_0$ because you can factor out $(z-z_0)^{k+1}$.

Comment: I dont understand the second line @cmk. Since $ f^{1}(z_{0})=0$ $f^{''}((z_{0})=0$ and also all derivatives so all $a_{n}=0$ except $a_{0}$. I can see $f(z_{0})=a_{0}$, right?

Comment: They never assumed that all of the derivatives are all zero at $z_0$. They only assumed that $f'(z_0)=0$.

Comment: But if $f^{'}(z_{0})=0$ does that not imply that other derivatives are zero?

Comment: Why would it? That's not true for many things, e.g. $z^2.$ You only know info at a point, not over a neighborhood.

Comment: my fault. It need not be.

Comment: What does 'Vanishes to order k+1' mean in the last sentence? The math makes sense.

Comment: It essentially just means what I wrote about factoring out $(z-z_0)^{k+1},$ so that $$\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{G(z)}{(z-z_0)^{k+1}}$$ is finite.